# Factory Pattern: Enum Parameter vs Explicit Method Name?

Tags: enums, factory-pattern

Say you have a factory that returns instances of ILightBulb.  Two ways (there may be more) of implementing the factory are as follows:

### Option 1 - Passing in an enum type

```
enum LightBulbType
{
    Incandescent,
    Halogen,
    Led,
}

class ILightBulbFactory
{
    public ILightBulb Create(LightBulbType type)
    {
        switch (type)
        {
            case LightBulbType.Incandescent:
                return new IncandescentBulb();
            case LightBulbType.Halogen:
                return new HalogenBulb();
            case LightBulbType.Led:
                return new LedBulb();
        }
    }
}
```

### Option 2 - Explicit method names

```
class ILightBulbFactory
{
    public ILightBulb CreateIncandescent()
    {
        return new IncandescentBulb();
    }

    public ILightBulb CreateHalogen()
    {
        return new HalogenBulb();
    }

    public ILightBulb CreateLed()
    {
        return new LedBulb();
    }
}
```

Which method is most preferable, and why?

Thanks.

Comment: The `I` at the beginning of methods is a naming convention for interfaces some people use. I don't see the point of naming classes ILightBulbFactory.

Comment: Also, both methods are bad and don't offer any advantage over just using constructors (unless you have real sub-types of the said types). Instead, pass an actual behavioral criterion based on which you want to create the object on and return the object based on that. If the factory method accepts the type or calls a method based on the type explicitly - you lose the point.

Comment: I didn't think I needed to clarify the fact that Incandescent, Halogen and Led were "real sub-types".  Maybe I am not seeing your point.  Also, I can think of at least one good reason for factory methods over using constructors - instantiation happens in one place.  So, if you have "new LedBulb()" all over your code base, and want to change it to use a "FluorescentBulb()", you only do it in the factory.  But I think that is off topic.  You lost me from this sentance onward: "Instead, pass an actual behavioral criterion...".  Perhaps you could clarify.

Comment: Changing the code saying `new LedBulb` is just as easy using any modern IDE with any refactoring abilities. What you want in a factory is to classify your `ILightBulb` members based on what _each one of them can do_. When you want polymorphic instantiation you don't want to say "LedBulb" explicitly for exactly the same reason you don't want to use `is` or `instanceof` (in C# or Java) (it's not really polymorphic). I'm talking about something like - `public ILightBulb Create(double luminosityRequired)` where creating the specific type of lightbulb has to do with an actual property of that type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In java, you can solve it in the enum, thus making sure that if you add new enums, all your code will remain working, instead of forgetting to add statements to your case.

```
enum LightBulbType
{
    Incandescent{

        @Override
        public ILightBulb getInstance() {
            return new IncandescentBulb();
        }

    },
    Halogen{

        @Override
        public ILightBulb getInstance() {
            return new HalogenBulb();
        }

    },
    Led{

        @Override
        public ILightBulb getInstance() {
            return new LedBulb();
        }

    };

    public abstract ILightBulb getInstance();
}

class ILightBulbFactory
{
    public ILightBulb Create(LightBulbType type)
    {
       return type.getInstance();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is brilliant!  This definitely answers the 'why' part of my question, and I love the use of polymorphism over the switch statement or the method names - truly OO.  Thanks a lot.  This will be my preferred pattern to use in the future.

Comment: Glad i could help, its my favourite pattern, its called the Strategy Pattern if you want to do more research on this ;)

Comment: @Pienterekaak If it is a Strategy Pattern why have you called the class ILightBulbFactory? Why Factory?

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent  for c# would be

```
public sealed class LightBulbType
{
    public static readonly LightBulbType Incandescent = new 
           LightBulbType("Incandescent", new IncandescentBulb());
    public static readonly LightBulbType Halogen = new 
           LightBulbType("Halogen", new HalogenBulb());
    public static readonly LightBulbType LedBulb = new LightBulbType("Led", 
           new LedBulb());

    public static IEnumerable<LightBulbType> Values
    {
        get
        {
            yield return Incandescent;
            yield return Halogen;
            yield return LedBulb;
        }
    }

    private string Name { get; set; }

    private ILightBulb Instance { get;}


    private LightBulbType(string name, ILightBulb instance)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.Instance = instance;
    }

    public override string ToString() => Name;

    public ILightBulb GetInstance()
    {
        return Instance;
    }
}

public interface ILightBulb
{
}

public class IncandescentBulb : ILightBulb
{
}

public class HalogenBulb : ILightBulb
{
}

public class LedBulb : ILightBulb
{
}

public static class LightBulbFactory
{
    public static ILightBulb Create(LightBulbType type)
    {
        return type.GetInstance();
    }
}

For call

ILightBulb halogenBulb = new HalogenBulb();
ILightBulb incandescentBulb = new IncandescentBulb();
ILightBulb ledBulb = new LedBulb();

or 

ILightBulb halo = LightBulbFactory.Create(LightBulbType.Halogen);
ILightBulb inca = LightBulbFactory.Create(LightBulbType.Incandescent);
ILightBulb led = LightBulbFactory.Create(LightBulbType.LedBulb);
```